# Write function for NLP String in R

Tags: r, string, nlp

This is a variation on a question I already asked, but there is a wrinkle that I think warrants a separate question. I using R to clean some text files. These are letters, that is, character strings. I'm using NLP, so these are NLP Strings, not base R strings. A simplified version looks like this:

```
library(NLP)

letter1 <- as.String(c("here is some text"))
letter2 <- as.String(c("and here is some more text"))
letter3 <- as.String(c("and this is the final one"))

list <- list(letter1 = letter1, letter2 = letter2, letter3 = letter3)
```

The problem occurs when I want to export these text files. (I want each letter in a separate text file, with the name of the file corresponding to its name in a list.) Given the solution posted in an earlier question, I used the following:

```
for (i in 1:length(list)) {
write.csv(list[i], file=paste0("~/desktop/", names(list)[i]))
}
```

When I do this, I get an error message saying `cannot coerce class ""String"" to a data.frame`. So I converted them to base R string, as follows:

```
list2 <- lapply(list, function(x){
x = toString(x)
x
})
```

This almost works. However, the output looks like this (for the first one):

```
"","letter1"
"1","here is some text"
```

I only want `here is some text`. I do not want `"", "letter1", or "1," or the quotation marks around`here is some text`. Is this possible?

Comment: When you do `write.csv` it output coumn headers by default. Try just adding `col.names=FALSE` to your `write.csv()` call.

Comment: Not sure if I placed it in the wrong place, but I get the warning `attempt to set 'col.names' ignored`.

Comment: A valid CSV has to have column names. Use `write.table` if you don't want them. Maybe `writeLines` would be preferable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My example must differ somewhat from my own data. The easiest solution for my data would be to use `cat()`, although that doesn't work for the example above. I'm going to post the answer here however in case it helps anyone. I'm not sure whether I sure edit the example or keep it like it is, to reflect the actual history.